# Question regarding understanding Dipole Moment

Tags: electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

I am trying to understand the meaning of the term ***Dipole Moment***,every definition or physical explanation involves some kind of hand wavy explanations ,I would like some concrete intuitive explanation of what Dipole Moment actually is .

The following integral from Griffiths $$p=\int r'ρ(r')dτ$$  ,is the formula for Dipole Moment ,how do I makes sense of this formula?

[image: Dipole Moment]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the dipole moment is a definition. Therefore, the definition has no proof. Only then can we generate insights at a level to understand why this definition is being defined.

Electrical charges may be far from each other for some reason. In this case, opposite charges tend to attract each other, while the same charges tend to repel each other. You can think of that.

In nature, substances want to be at the lowest energy level in general there are no external forces. Therefore, they will tend to become neutral from the charged state by reducing the distance between negative and positive charges. Because you can think of the neutral state as the steady state. However, as I mentioned at the beginning, these charges may not come together for some reason. Let's consider batteries, for example. It has plus and minus poles. And whenever there is a minus and plus charge group separated from each other you can name it a dipole.

And a full battery is unstable in terms of load. And opposite charges have a desire to attract each other. Here you can understand how much these opposite charges want to attract each other by looking at the dipole moment.

At this point, the concept of potential comes into play. Because as you see, the potential is directly proportional to the dipole moment. If the dipole moment is high, you can interpret that the voltage of the battery is different from zero and the charge is not finished because the charges did not meet with each other. But for V=0, you can say the battery is dead because r = 0 in the formula of p.

Charges have become stable by converging with each other. And therefore, the ultimate fate of the charges in excited state flow (current) has stopped at the end.

Looking at the dimension analysis of the dipole moment at this point, p=[Q].[L], (charge)*(length) is actually only related to the concepts of p charge and distance. So by looking briefly at the value of the dipole moment, you can tell how much the charges are willing to neutralize each other. In this case, you can also consider that the types of molecular bonds are modeled to understand this dipole moment's relationship.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Electric dipole moment is defined as the product of charge and distance between them.
P=qxl where q maybe the charge of any one of the charges (positive/negative),modulus is taken l is seperation between them.note these charges must be equal to contribute a dipole. Now what is dipole moment ? It is the tendency of a system of charges to align with external electric field. The steady state of dipole within external electric field is where dipole moment is placed parallel to electric field, now greater the dipole moment greater the tendency of dipole to align with external electric field. This can be verified with the formula t=PxE where t is torue p is dipole moment e is external electric field.